# most efficient Java data structure for searching triples of strings

Tags: java, search

Suppose I have a large list (around 10,000 entries) of string triples as such:

```
car    noun    yes
dog    noun    no
effect noun    yes
effect verb    no
```

Suppose I am presented with a string double - for example, (effect, verb) - and I need to quickly look in the list to see if the pair appears and, if it does, whether its value is yes or no. (For this example the double does appear and the value is "no".)

What is the best data structure in Java to store the list and the most efficient way to perform the search? I am running hundreds of thousands of these searches so speed is of the essence.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might consider using a `HashMap<YourDouble, String>`.  Searches will be O(1).

You could either create an object, YourDouble which holds the first two values, or else append one to the other -- if values will still be unique -- and use `HashMap<String, String>`.

Comment: Hi there,

Do you mean that I should concatenate the first two strings to make the key?

Comment: I'm saying it may be an option for you.  If you can guarantee that the resulting key is still unique.  It really depends upon your data.  Using String instead just allows you to avoid creating the YourDouble object.

Comment: All the answers have been helpful and suggest a HashMap. I'll work with HashMap<Pair, String>.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a [`HashMultimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashMultimap.html) for each type of search you want, e.g. "all three", "each pair", and "each single field". When you build the list, populate all the different maps, then you can fetch from whichever map is appropriate for your query.

(The downside is that you'll need a type for at least each arity, e.g. use just String for the "single field" maps, but a `Pair` for the two-field maps, and a `Triple` for the three-field map.)

Comment: I'm only going to need to search on the first pair, so I guess a HashMap with Pair is the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `HashMap` where the key is the concatenation of the first two strings, the ones which you'll use for lookups, and the value is a Boolean, representing the `yes` and `no` strings.

Alternatively, it seems the words in the second column would be fewer, since they represent categories. You could have a `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Boolean>>` where you first index by e.g. "noun", "verb" etc. and then you index by e.g. "car", "dog", "effect", to get to your boolean. This would probably be more space-efficient.

Comment: Why not simple use a HashMap, with a key containing the two first strings and redefining equals and hashCode (i.e. a Pair<String, String>)? This is much better than concatenation and a map of maps.

Comment: The concatenation is probably a bad idea, you're right. But the map of maps might have its benefits _if_, as I've said, he doesn't have many distinct strings in the second column.

Comment: Yes, there are just 5 possibilities for the second column

Comment: In that case, I'm almost tempted to suggest an enum instead of a string for the second column, if that's applicable. Apparently there's even a class called [`EnumMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) which you could use, which I assume would use a simple array instead of a hashtable.

Answer (score 1):

10k doesn't seem that large to me. Have you tried a DB?

The place to look for information like this is the [Semantic Web](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_Web). A number of projects work on [Triple Stores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triplestore) of just this type. There's a list at the bottom of the Triple Store page of implementations.

As far as java is concerned your algorithms are almost certainly going to be language dependent and if you find a good algorithm implemented in C its java port will also be fast.

Also, what's your data set look like? Are there a lot of 2 matches such that subject and verb are often the same? How many matches are you expecting to get? MapReduce will work work well for finding one match in 10k but won't work as well doing a query that returns a 8k of 10k where the query can't be easily partitioned.

There's a query language made just for this problem too: [SPARQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARQL). The [bigdata blog](http://www.bigdata.com/bigdata/blog/) has some good insights, though again 10k doesn't seem that large.